# linux: adding hosts programmatically?

Tags: linux, dns

Is there a way to programmatically add hosts to the local name resolver under Linux?

I would rather avoid fiddling with /etc/hosts dynamically...

**Example:**  add the name *foo* and bind it to the local port 127.1.2.3

**Use Case:** I have an application installed locally accessible through a web browser. I'd like the application to be accessible through a local URI.

Comment: I'd say this is serverfault material

Comment: It relates to how to perform this task programatically, so SO is right in my opinion.

Comment: Binding a host name to a host:port? Does that mean you want connections to foo on ANY port to connect to localhost:9999 instead? If so, you'll need more than DNS config.

Comment: The problem is that he's asking about how to modify DNS records dynamically, which has nothing to do directly with programming. So this is a serverfault question in disguise. In fact, given his edit of trying to map ip:port to a name, it seems that he could use some serverfault reading :-)

Comment: Why don't you explain what you want to do instead of how to do what you think is the solution?

Comment: @Jean-Lou: Just edit the /etc/hosts file programmatically. Save a copy when you begin and if you fail, restore the copy. For such a trivial use that should be more than enough. Everything else will be killing flies with lasers

Comment: I suppose you could write your own nss plugin and configure it in /etc/nsswitch.conf if you really don't want to much with /etc/hosts or run your own nameserver, but that definitely counts as "killing flies with lasers" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> add the name *foo* and bind it to the local port 127.0.0.1:9999

What is it that you want?  You can add `foo 127.0.0.1` to [`hosts`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts) or do the equivalent in your nameserver, but a connection to `foo` on port 1234 will always go to `127.0.0.1:1234` -- it's not possible to redirect that to port 9999 based on name, which is lost by the time [`connect`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) is called.

On Linux you can add IPs to the loopback device (i.e. `ip addr add 127.1.2.3 dev lo`), and then use [`iptables`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) to change all connections destined for 127.1.2.3:1234 to instead go to 127.0.0.1:9999, but I can't tell from your question if that the observable behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

The google search term you want is "DDNS" for "Dynamic DNS".  That's a technology for dynamically adding records to DNS servers, which sounds like exactly what you want.  I'm pretty sure the bind in most lunix distros supports it, but you may need to read up on how to configure it.

Comment: The OP asked for manipulation of the "local name resolver". DDNS is a solution, but not a "local" one (and not the easiest).

Answer (score 1):

If you'll only add hosts, a pretty safe way to do it is

```
echo -e "ip.add.re.ss\thostname" >> /etc/hosts
```

Now, if you want to remove them it starts getting hairy. I suspect you also want to remove them.

If this is the case you can use Dynamic DNS, for example, BIND has the nsupdate tool to update zone files:

```
       $ nsupdate
       > update delete oldhost.example.com A
       > update add newhost.example.com 86400 A 172.16.1.1
       > send
```

This does the following:

> Any A records for oldhost.example.com
>   are deleted. And an A record for
>   newhost.example.com with IP address
>   172.16.1.1 is added. The newly-added record has a 1 day TTL (86400
>   seconds).

Comment: Could I be binding the name "foo" to the local address 127.0.0.1 on port 9999 for example?

Comment: DNS maps IP addresses to names, ports are not part of IP addresses. So, no.

Comment: @vinko: How do you get nsupdate to only update the *local dns cache* and not try to communicate with others name servers?

Comment: You cannot: dynamic update updates a zone, not a cache. Updating the cache cannot be done by standard ways (each resolver may have its own proprietary way, which one do you use?)

Comment: @bortzmeyer: Is there another way?  i.e is the local cache accessible another way?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be going with a recent discovery: multicast-dns using the Avahi package. An example can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KubuntuZeroconf).